# convert from ndip to dip

Tags: breadboard, dip

I have a V9958 NDIP (Narrow DIP) chip that I would like to use with a breadboard, is it possible to somehow convert NDIP to DIP or use an external adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shrink Dip is a non-standard variation of DIP ics. Narrow normally refers to the width of the ic at 0.3" inches (and Wide at 0.6"), while Shrink refers to the pitch of the leads. A typical DIP ic should have 0.1" pitch, while Shink DIP has 0.07" spacing. SOIC has 0.05" for comparrison.

The quickest way to use a Shrink DIP in a standard 0.1" pitch breadboard, is to use an adaptor. Make or buy a custom pcb. Or if you need to use multiple of them without soldering, a ZIF adaptor is better.

If you need one right away, a cheap and ugly method is using some pref board, headers, and wire. Solder the headers on the pref board, then Glue the chip upside down on the pref board. Then solder some wires from the leads to the header. Dead Bug style. Won't win a beauty contest though.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, if you have a SDIP chip, the pin spacing has 0.07 spacing. Because of this, there's a unique trick you could use without having to dead-bug it and solder wires all over the place!

If you place the IC **diagonally**...

*No need to buy expensive adapters, or glue the IC down and solder wires all over the place.*

Pitch of the SDIP: `1.778mm`
2.54 * (1 / sqrt 2) = `1.796mm`

[image: Place the chip diagonally]

In fact, there's even a specialized protoboard which does this:

[image: Special PCB]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested here is the datasheet: [link](http://www.msxarchive.nl/pub/msx/docs/datasheets/v9938.pdf).
As per page 134 the correct name of this kind of package is 'shrink dip' (narrow is apparently used only for SOIC or smd-ish packages). Searching the web with the correct keyword leads to a ton of [results](https://www.google.it/search?q=shrink%20dip%20adapter&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=_wh9U4jHOMfI0wWd84CwAw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=965). Check on rs, mouser, digikey or with your local electronics goodies dealer and you can start coding on your chip with a nice reusable adapter:
[image: shrink dip]